# Providing initial text for the readline buffer

Tags: c++, readline, default-value

In a readline buffer I want to provide an initial value the user can edit. This can either be a default value or the old value of the field already saved to my database. The entered value shall not be added to the readline-history as it is only "data" not a command.

From the samples here and on the internet I have learned that this code should do the job:

```
char *deftext;

int MatCustom::set_deftext ()
{
    // cout << "set_deftext called ... deftext: " << deftext << endl;
    if (deftext)
    {
        // cout << "inserting..." << endl;
        rl_insert_text(deftext);
        // rl_line_buffer = deftext;
        // cout << rl_stuff_char('J') << endl;
        rl_redisplay();

        deftext = (char *)NULL;

        rl_startup_hook = (rl_hook_func_t *)NULL;
        // rl_pre_input_hook = (rl_hook_func_t *)NULL;
    };
    return 0;
}

string MatCustom::getlineWithoutHistory(const string &field) {
    string returnString;
    const char *buffer;
    char *cstr = new char[field.length() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr, field.c_str());

    deftext = cstr;
    // cout << "Deftext in getLineWithoutHistory: " << deftext << endl;
    rl_startup_hook = set_deftext;
    // rl_pre_input_hook = set_deftext;

    buffer = :: readline("");

    if (buffer != nullptr) {
        returnString = buffer;
    } else {
        returnString = "";
    }
    free((void *) buffer);
    delete [] cstr;

    return returnString;
}
```

It works perfectly well to convert my old value to a `char*` and pass it to the global variable `deftext`, because a parameter cannot be given to the readline-hook-functions.

I am experiencing problems: Whenever I use the `rl_startup_hook`, which is said to be called before the prompt gets printed, I find this this hook never gets executed. However, when I use the `rl_pre_input_hook`, which is called prior to the input to begin, my function `set_deftext` actually gets called. This functions finds `deftext` set.

Still, I don't get any text inserted into the input buffer. The function `rl_insert_text` produces no change – even when I use `rl_redisplay()`. Directly changing the buffer with `rl_line_buffer = deftext;` also has no effect. When I try `cout << rl_stuff_char('J') << endl;` for debugging just to insert a single `char`, nothing happens and the function returns `0` indicating an unsuccessful insert.

Both functions are static member functions. I usually call my function with

```
input = MatCustom::getlineWithoutHistory(rawValue);
```

to edit to provided value (rawValue).

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Is `MatCustom::set_deftext` a *`static`* member function or not?

Comment: Edited my question accordingly.